# How to publish to Facebook page stream and appear as application instead of user

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-graph-api

**Background:**

I have successfully used the Facebook Graph API to publish activity on a particular web site to a Facebook fan page's stream (wall).

To do this I had to create a Facebook application for the web site and add it to my own Facebook user profile, with necessary authorizations.

**Problem:**

I don't want all the status updates to be associated with my personal Facebook user profile. I'd like the updates to look like they came from the Facebook application for the web site without identifying my personal profile. BTW, I'm pretty sure Facebook prohibits a person having multiple user profiles.

**Question:**

Is there a way for a Facebook application to post status updates to a stream and not have it look like it came from a particular user profile (i.e. either the application itself or anonymously)?If not, is there some other way to accomplish my goal of posting status updates to a page without identifying my personal profile?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a profile for your company / website and publish updates through that.  This is common practice.

Think about it this way.  Who's profile should updates for Coca-Cola, Inc be published through?  The CEO? The Marketing Director?  Neither.  Coca-Cola get's it's own company profile.  So should your website.

Comment: I think what you're saying is that setting up the fan page is the wrong approach. I should set up a profile for the company/website and authorize the application to post on behalf of that profile. Thanks - That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I thought the answer seemed reasonable but runs contrary to the Facebook terms and conditions. Specifically. there is no way to have a profile just for a company or web site. 

I then learned that when a page administrator posts on the page's wall it appears as if the post came from the page and not their personal account, which is great. Unfortunately there is no way to do this right now using the graph API as I was attempting because of the Facebook bug described here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10005